# Why is the wrong texture showing when I switch from texture paint to object mode?

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting

I've just finished texture painting this model, and I wanted to start rigging it and whatnot, but when I try and go from texture paint to object mode, an older version of the texture appears. I have the right texture selected, I have no idea why the wrong texture is showing on the model.

Another weird thing is that I've already done this exact model once before with a different texture paint, and that one went perfectly fine. Unfortunately, I can't remember what I did with the first model that I haven't done with the second model.

This is what it looks like in Texture Paint, and this is how I want it to look:

[image: Desired texture]

This is how it looks in object mode, with an older texture that I've since painted over:

[image: Old texture]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try making a new copy of the desired art and give it an unique name that doesn't match the same name as the other texture. Load that new image as a texture in the material texture channel, and then in the uv image editor select the offending image texture and shift-click the X to delete it from the file, and then save the file and reopen it. (This is important - don't close your file until you have made sure that your new texture is saved to disk and can be opened outside of blender).

Comment: I can help if you share the blend file through [blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com)

Comment: The image you painted on wasn't saved. You should try to press Image > Save Image in UV/Image Editor, probably this will invoke update in other interaction modes besides Textture Paint.

Comment: As Mr Zak said, you need to save edits to your texture manually.

Answer (score 0):

So unfortunately these answers didn't work, and I still have no idea why it was doing that since it worked with the other identical file, but when I switched it to cycles render I was able to use a texture node, and that seemed to fix the problem. Thanks for the suggestions.